# Showing a element on click and hiding on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element that is hidden on scroll down and appears back when i scroll back up. I am trying to create a scenario when once the div is hidden, it can re-appear on a click of a link irrespective of the scroll position.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 180) {
    $('.header-avail')
 .attr('style', 'display: block !important;')
 .fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.header-avail').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
body {height: 2000px;}

#primary-menu {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 250px;
 
}
#primary-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1.154em;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
 
}

.show-contact{background: green !important;}

.header-avail{display:none !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">

<li id="menu-item-386" class="header-avail menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-386"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Contact Us</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-504" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-504" style="display: inline-block !important;"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Check Availability</span></a></li>

<li id="menu-item-504" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-504 show-contact" style="display: inline-block !important;"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Show Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you want the element to always stay visible after the click?

Comment: @CumminUp07 yes

Comment: As a side note, I find it very disturbing (in terms of UI) when the elements of a webpage are constantly *twinkling*.

Comment: @CumminUp07 any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: I posted an answer for you, it appears to be working both here and in a fiddle I made, let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

I would set a flag to see when the element has been clicked and then incorporate that into your scroll logic, like this:

```js
var show_flag = false;
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 180 || show_flag) {
    $('.header-avail')
 .attr('style', 'display: block !important;')
 .fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.header-avail').fadeOut();
  }
});

$('.show-contact').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  $('.header-avail').attr('style', 'display: block !important;');
  show_flag = true;
})
```

```css
body {height: 2000px;}

#primary-menu {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 250px;
 
}
#primary-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1.154em;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
 
}

.show-contact{background: green !important;}

.header-avail{display:none !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">

<li id="menu-item-386" class="header-avail menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-386"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Contact Us</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-504" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-504" style="display: inline-block !important;"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Check Availability</span></a></li>

<li id="menu-item-504" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-504 show-contact" style="display: inline-block !important;"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Show Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('.header-avail').css('display','none')
$('.show-contact').on("click", function(){
$('.header-avail').fadeIn();
 })
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  
  if (y > 180) {  
  
    $('.header-avail').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.header-avail').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
body {height: 2000px;}

#primary-menu {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 150px;
 
}
#primary-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1.154em;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
 
}

.show-contact{background: green !important;}

.header-avail{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">

<li id="menu-item-386" class="header-avail menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-386"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Contact Us</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-504" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-504" style="display: inline-block !important;"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Check Availability</span></a></li>

<li id="menu-item-504" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-504 show-contact" style="display: inline-block !important;"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Show Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

This?

***[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ryanhssn/q5u9bvqw/3/)***

Comment: No, this does not make the div appear when the Show Contact link is clicked.

Comment: the problem with this is that the page scrolls back to the top

Comment: No, It's bug here.

Comment: Please check by adding on fiddle.

Comment: the div does not stay open. It closes once you scroll down after click the link

Comment: Check fiddle in edited answer. If worked  marked accepted. If not, then I cant say exactly what do you want to achieve. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort but it still doesn't seem to  work as on click, page reloads and scrolls back to top